# Kernel of the local-global map for first galois cohomology of $m$-torsion group

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, elliptic-curves, galois-cohomology

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over a number field $K$. Are there examples when the local-global map $$H^1(K,E[m])\to \prod_\nu H^1(K_\nu,E_{K_\nu}[m])$$ has a nontrivial kernel?

I know that if we compose this map with $\prod_\nu H^1(K_\nu,E_{K_\nu}[m])\to \prod_\nu H^1(K_\nu,E_{K_\nu})[m]$ the kernel of the composition is called Selmer group and it often turnes out to be nontrivial.

Comment: I don’t think so – the Selmer group usually involves cohomology classes that have prescribed ramification. I’m not entirely sure about the details of the definition, but this looks more related to the Tate-Shafarevich group…

Comment: The elements of $H^1(K, E[m])$ are in bijective correspondence with so-called $m$-coverings. In particular you are looking for an elliptic curve which has an $m$-covering with everywhere local points, but no global points. An example is given by the Selmer cubic $3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5z^3 = 0$ viewed as a $3$-covering of its Jacobian.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Can you explain where do we see the 3-covering of its Jacobian?

Comment: @Mummytheturkey I also don't see a 3-covering structure. Could you explain that?

Comment: @reuns If you are happy with a mysterious but explicit answer then you can just check that the Jacobian is $y^2 = x^3 - 24300$ and the morphism given by $C \to E : (x:y:z) \mapsto \left(\frac{16 y^6 + 20 y^3 z^3 + 25 z^6}{(xyz)^2}, \frac{64 y^9 + 120 y^6 z^3 - 150 y^3 z^6 - 125 z^9}{(xyz)^3} \right)$ is an explicit $3$-covering. In general it is a theorem that an $n$-covering ($n > 2$) with everywhere local points may be embedded in $\mathbb{P}^{n-1}$, and the converse.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Over an extension it is an isogeny, right? So the dual isogeny is not defined over $\Bbb{Q}$? (as the Selmer cubic is famous for having no $\Bbb{Q}$-point)

Comment: @reuns this is not an isogeny over $\mathbb{Q}$ since $C$ does not even have a $\mathbb{Q}$ point, that is implicitly part of the data. Indeed once you pick the identity, you could compute the dual isogeny (of course it could be an isogeny and a translation composed if you chose a silly point)... it won't be defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Geometrically, this is even more explicit than an isogeny... it is literally multiplication by $3$, twisted by an isomorphism.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Thank you for this explanation! Can an example for an arbitrary $m$ be constructed in a similar way?
As far as I understand, it is not enough that the total space of an $m$-cover has a point for the cover to be trivial, otherwise map $H^1(K,E[m])\to H^1(K,E)[m]$ would be injective but it has kernel $E(K)/mE(K)$. That is why, we cannot just take a non-trivial element in $m$-torsion of Tate-Shafarevich group of $E$ and lift it to $H^1(K,E[m])$.

Comment: @Rex Indeed, the cover has to be trivial in the sense that the (unique) isomorphism you get by declaring your point to be sent to $O$ on $E$ must also behave with the covering structure. For example if $P \not\in nE(K)$ then $(E, \tau_P \circ [n])$ is a nontrivial $n$-covering which is clearly trivial in $H^1(K, E)$.

Comment: @rex That's a good point and I see that I've missed the real subtlety of your question. You're asking for an element of sha which is everywhere locally trivial *as a covering*! I guess this means that one needs a $K_v$-point to live in $\psi^{-1}(mE(K_v))$ where $\psi: C \to E$ is the covering map. hmmmm